# PHP, How do I clear this form after submit?

Tags: php

Having trouble with posting the code's. I hope this is better?
I have a contact form that after filling out and clicking send, it doesn't clear the form, you can just keep clicking send and it keeps on sending.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clearing"?

Comment: Where is the form? (please show it)

Comment: You mean the values are in the form after it was processed?

Comment: Could be the browser caching it.

Comment: You are outputting the posted values as the content of the value attribute of your inputs resp. as the content of your textarea. If you don’t want that – then simply _don’t do it_. Add an additional check before outputting these values whether the mail was send or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// on submit...
$("#contactForm #submit").click(function() {
    $("#error").hide();

(...here your setting..)

function success(){
        $("#sent-form-msg").fadeIn();
        $("#contactForm").fadeOut();
     }

    return false;
});
```

and add this script to your html form :

```
            <!-- form -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="link of script"></script>
```

i hope that  help you

Answer (score -3):

As I see in the end you send a mail, I belive you must after that reload the page so the form apear with no data in it.

Comment: Please post a complete answer with code. Though, at this time you're guessing because we don't have enough information to answer the question. Not good because now it looks, in the list of questions, like the question has an answer.